# Can't find my local integration services to connect

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis, ssas, ssms

I have SQL Server 2014 Entreprise Edition with SSIS, SSRS, SSAS, and SSMS 2016 installed on my machine.
When i want to connect to my SSIS from SSMS 2016, unlike for SSAS and SSRS i can't see the Server of SSIS and when i type its name and click connect, i got an error.

> The connection to the Integration Services service on the "KHALIL-HP"
>   computer failed with the following error: "The specified service does
>   not exist as an installed service. ". This error may occur when you
>   try to connect to a SQL Server 2005 Integration Services service from
>   the current version of SQL Server Tools. Instead, add folders to the
>   service configuration file to allow the local Integration Services
>   service to manage packages on the SQL Server 2005 instance.

[image: fff]

Considering that i've verified the DCOM config and execute SSMS as Admin what can be the problème.

Comment: What server name do you use when trying to connect to SSIS? It should be KHALIL-HP. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Yes, i try to connect with "Khalil-Hp"

Comment: and this is the message that i get : 
`La connexion au service Integration Services sur l'ordinateur « KHALIL-HP » a échoué avec l'erreur suivante : « Le service spécifié n’existe pas en tant que service installé. ».

Cette erreur peut se produire lorsque vous tentez de vous connecter à un service SQL Server 2005 Integration Services à partir de la version actuelle des outils SQL Server. À la place, ajoutez des dossiers au fichier de configuration du service pour permettre au service Integration Services local de gérer des packages sur l'instance SQL Server 2005.`

Comment: The traslation in english : The connection to the Integration Services service on the "KHALIL-HP" computer failed with the following error: "The specified service does not exist as an installed service. ". This error may occur when you try to connect to a SQL Server 2005 Integration Services service from the current version of SQL Server Tools. Instead, add folders to the service configuration file to allow the local Integration Services service to manage packages on the SQL Server 2005 instance.

Comment: This may be of help to you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137789.aspx

Comment: Did you create the SSIS catalog?

Comment: No i couldn't even reach this step

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the SSIS Service is started.

Comment: Although this did not turn out to be the solution for this poster, I am going to leave this answer up as it may help future readers who have the same question.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this exact same error.

In the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/service/integration-services-service-ssis-service) within R. Richards' comment it said:

> This service is not required to create, save, and run Integration
>   Services packages. SQL Server 2012 supports the Integration Services
>   service for backward compatibility with earlier releases of
>   Integration Services.

In order to create the SSIS catalogue, we had to reinstall making sure to check the Integration Services option.

Once we had done that, we were able to create the SSIS catalogue.

So in summary, connection to Integration Services when starting up SSMS is unnecessary for 2012+ since you can create to the Database Engine and execute SSIS packages from the catalogue without. It is just there for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Connecting Integration Services in SSMS doesn't apply to SSIS 2012+. That's for previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned in Microsoft site,

> Starting in SQL Server 2012 (11.x), Integration Services stores
> objects, settings, and operational data in the SSISDB database for
> projects that you've deployed to the Integration Services server using
> the project deployment model.

For Reference

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/service/integration-services-service-ssis-service?view=sql-server-ver16